# iOS: The grey screen between Default.png and the first OpenGL ES frame

Tags: ios, eaglview, cadisplaylink

I'm trying to port my previous openGL iPhone app to use Xcode's new OpenGL ES template, which uses CADisplayLink.

WHat I've noticed is that after Default.png is displayed, and before the first frame is drawn, there is a grey screen in between that sits there while my app processes the loading things on the first frame.

How do you extend the Default.png displaying all the way until the first frame is ready to be drawn?